# Get Apple UIAlertController completion when using StoreKit

Tags: ios, swift, storekit, uialertcontroller

I'm implementing a payment ViewController, where I want to present a loading view (spinner), whenever StoreKit is fetching some data. I add the loading view when the "Purchase" button is clicked, and removes it when `func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse)` is called.

The problem is that the loadingView is still running while the "Sign In to iTunes Store" (among others) is still shown. Is there any way that I can get/override the completion block of the Apple generated UIAlertControllers?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using [MKStoreKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit)?

I had issues with StoreKit, but moved on to code like this with MKStoreKit.

```
let notification = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
func purchase() {
    MKStoreKit.sharedKit().initiatePaymentRequestForProductWithIdentifier("YOURIDENTIFIER")
    self.notification.addObserverForName(kMKStoreKitProductPurchaseFailedNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue()) {
        (note) -> Void in
        // It failed for some reason
        self.hideLoadingView() 
    }

    self.notification.addObserverForName(kMKStoreKitProductPurchasedNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue()) {
        (note) -> Void in
        // It was purchased
        self.hideLoadingView() 
    }

    self.notification.addObserverForName(kMKStoreKitProductPurchaseDeferredNotification, object: nil, queue: NSOperationQueue()) {
        (note) -> Void in
        // It was canceled 
        self.hideLoadingView()         
    }
}

func hideLoadingView() {
    // Do whatever you need to
}
```

Made things much easier to manage